# Convert Image element with CSS3 filters to a Blob

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

Assuming the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="image-blob" class="filter-wrapper">
    <img id="pic" src="">
</div>
```

I'm applying CSS3 filters such as `-webkit-filter: blur(1px) brightness(1.5) contrast(1.8) drop-shadow(black 16px 16px 20px) grayscale(0.2) hue-rotate(90deg) invert(0.1) saturate(3.6) sepia(0.3);` to the `<img>` element.

Is it possible to convert this rendered image with the filters into a blob which is to be downloaded by the end-user without involving any server side process / proxy?

**Note**: Client-side download is being done using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) and possible conversion to canvas using [HTML2Canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html)

**Edit:**

Further investigation shows that this might not be possible (proving this wrong is most welcomed) and the only solution might be to replicate these filters via javascript in the canvas itself. [Pixel Manipulation Tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/) or a solid library such as [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/).

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. The only way to save post-CSS-processed imagery to disk is to hit *alt-PrtScr* on the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@NielsKeurentjes correctly points out that browsers prevent javascript from saving of most web page content locally for security concerns.

However, I offer that you could use canvas to do your image filters.

Then simply convert the canvas to an image and open the modified image by itself in a new browser tab.

Instruct the user to "right-click-save-as" and you're good.

I suggest this method for a couple of reasons:

- Users are often aware of (and comfortable with) the right-click-save-as method.
- Even if you find a hack to force JS save locally, browsers will consider the hack a security concern and eventually forbid the hack.  Not to mention, hacks are almost always cross-browser nightmares.

BTW:

In addition to CamanJS, Pixastic is another good image filter library:

http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/